# Matplotlib Polar scatter plot doesn't show all points

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm trying to do a simple polar scatter plot in Matplotlib, here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar = True)
c = ax.scatter([-1.3,.4,-.2],[1,1.5,2])
```

For some reason, the plot doesn't include all of the points, it only shows me the point with radius 1. How do I make it automatically show all of the points, or how can I fix the radius of the plot myself? I am running this in a Jupyter notebook, if that makes any difference.

Comment: This looks fine on my end. Which versions of matplotlib and python are you using?

Comment: I'm using matplotlib version 3.1.3 and python version 3.7.6

Answer (score 1):

This is what I suggest if I understand your question correctly this code plots all the points automatically

Here I am just using for loop to loop through all the points

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar = True)
a = [1,1.5,2]
for idx, i in enumerate([-1.3,.4,-.2]):
    c = ax.scatter([i],[a[idx]])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm actually a bit confused on why this worked but my code didn't... I feel like it shouldn't take several lines of code to plot something so simple, no?

Comment: you don't need to loop through the points to get them to show

Comment: Paul, I'm not sure what you mean. If I don't loop through the points then it's essentially the same as my original code, which isn't working for me for whatever reason...